# Route filter in netflix zuul

Tags: reverse-proxy, netflix-zuul

I am using netflix zuul for front-end of system. In pre filter, I select an appropriate backend server for the request. I want to use route filter to route request to the selected backend. Backends are other machines whose IP the system knows. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to use route filter. Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/1.x/zuul-simple-webapp/src/main/groovy/filters/route/SimpleHostRoutingFilter.groovy

Comment: https://gist.github.com/abouchelit/283d6f4a667ec36d5d65#file-simpleroutefilter-java